# Alert on Closing window in Window Form Application in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted that when user closes the window in (Window Form Application, C#) by clicking (X) or pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> key or by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, an alert will show i.e a Dialog(containing two buttons OK & CANCEL).
How to do?

Comment: What have U tried so far?

Comment: Use `Form.FormClosing` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this by a simple search!

Handle `Closing` event of your form:

```
this.Closing += OnClosing; // For example put this in the constructor of your form

private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs cancelEventArgs)
{
        string msg = "Do you want to close this?";
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(msg, "Close Confirmation",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo/*Cancel*/, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            /* Do something */;
        else if (result == DialogResult.No)
            cancelEventArgs.Cancel = false;

}
```

Comment: … and set `cancelEventArgs.Cancel` to cancel the closure.

Comment: Yes, fine, but don't you think that this answer misses the most important part?

Comment: @Ali Sepehri.Kh but how to generate that alert which contain OK & CANCEL button

Comment: @Steve: Yes, I had forgotten it. Thank you.

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh thanks dude its work, great work :)

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh its great help done by you, i am working on this from last 5 hours and getting nothing. Thank you soo much dude :)

Comment: Remember that cancelEventArgs contains also the reason for the closing event. Sometimes is not very advisable to deny a system shutdown request.

Comment: @Steve: That was something, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you could do this at application level

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.ApplicationExit += Application_ApplicationExit;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += Application_ApplicationExit;
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    static void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something
    }
```